# VBA to copy website data

Tags: html, vba, excel

Can someone help to point me in a right direction on how to copy a particular data from a website to excel sheet via VBA?

I tried using macro recorder and web query but it keeps showing error script and the yellow arrow didn't show up at the part that i want to copy.

This is the website that i'm trying to copy http://etfdb.com/etf/EEM/#holdings

I only want to copy the Top Ten Holdings part.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Edit : This is my current code but nothing showed up, can someone tell me whats wrong?

```
Sub Get123()

Dim oHtml       As HTMLDocument
Dim oElement    As Object

Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument

With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
    .Open "GET", "http://etfdb.com/etf/EEM/#holdings", False
    .send
    oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

For Each oElement In oHtml.getElementsByClassName("holdings-left-content")
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = oElement.Value
Next oElement

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried to use the code tag for the code but it seems doesn't work...sorry about that :(

Comment: When you enter yout question, there are curly brackets at the top.  Select your code then click those brackets to add four spaces to the beginning of every line.

Comment: I did that, tried it several times but doesn't work, i posted a question before with the code tag and it worked though..not sure whats the problem..:(

Comment: The curly brackets worked for me.  I briefly looked at your tags before deleting them.  I think you had <pre> at the beginning and <code> at the end.  You need <pre> and </pre>.

Comment: Yeah, i tried to use the curly bracket at first but since it doesn't work i tried to type it manually..haha, anyway you already fixed it for me, thankss, will try to to put it properly again next time :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with WINHTTP request but I'm assuming your having trouble because it's not waiting for a response from the server.

I tend to do web scraping this way:

```
Sub extract()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim html As HTMLDocument

    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    IE.Visible = False
    IE.Navigate2 "http://etfdb.com/etf/EEM/#holdings"

    ' Wait while IE loading
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Set html = IE.document
    Set holdingsClass = html.getElementsByClassName("holdings-left-content")

    Range("A1").Value = holdingsClass(0).textContent

    'Cleanup
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

Make sure you have a reference to:

1. Microsoft Internet Controls
2. Microsoft HTML Object Library

---

Since the class contains a list the return text is all in one element.  So the results look like this:

[image]

---

Here is one way to split the results up into different cells :

```
Dim results As Variant
results = Split(holdingsClass(0).textContent, vbLf)

cntr = 1
For i = LBound(results) To UBound(results)
    If Trim(results(i)) <> "" Then
        Select Case Right(Trim(results(i)), 1)
            Case ":"
                Range("B" & cntr) = CStr(Trim(results(i)))
            Case "%"
                Range("C" & cntr).Value = Trim(results(i))
                cntr = cntr + 1
            Case 0
                Range("C" & cntr).Value = Trim(results(i))
            Case Else
                Range("A" & cntr).Value = Trim(results(i))
        End Select
    End If
Next i
```

---

Results:

[image]

---

**Explanation**

`getElements...` returns an array of all html elements that meet the given criteria.  In this case it returns all elements with the class name "holdings-left-content".

Since there is only one element with this class name we access the first element using `(0)` because it's a zero based array (0,1,2 for 3 elements instead of 1,2,3).

The `Split` method takes all text in first array element and separates each line into another array (results) using the carriage return `vbLf` as a delimiter.

Now we just loop through the results array and display each line of text.  The `Select Case` just helps us know which column to display the next line of text for a nicely formatted display.

Comment: Hi Portland, thank you so much for spending your time helping me out. I tried the code just now but i got the error " Run Time Error '-2147467259 (80004005)' Automation error Unspecified Error ". When i click debug it highlight 'Set html = IE.document' this part of the code , I already set both of the reference that you mentioned btw and i'm using IE10 if that makes any difference? 1 more thing, the error showed up even before the page finish loading :(

Comment: Sorryyy, i tried to change Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium into Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") , and now it worked!!! Thank you so muchhh!!! hahaha, really appreciate it ^^, if its not too much may i ask if its possible to make the outcome become more tidy, like column A contain the company name, B contain the symbol/ticker and C contain the Percentage?

Comment: See my edit, I've updated the last bit of code & result image to make the output more readable.  It's a little hacky but looks better.

Comment: Thanks Portland!! You are the man !! Really appreciate this ^^

Comment: Hi Portland, i know that i have mark this case as answered but may i know what does this line of code mean? "holdingsclass(0)", why its using (0) , the reason im asking this is because i don't understand what it means and also the code seems to be so unstable, sometimes it misses to get the data, error sometimes occur on this line of code "results = Split(holdingsClass(0).textContent, vbLf)" Hope someone can enlighten me, thanks!!

Comment: I added an explanation of the code in question to the post (Too long for comment :-).  The error might be due to the page not loading fast enough (common issue with this technique).  You might try increasing the wait time inside the `do while` loop.  Play with the 1 by increasing it and seeing if you have better stability.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this method here but it wasn't working for me. I found [Pull Web Page Into Worksheet](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=70823) on **Ozgrid** from user **JerryD** and I am including it here, for future reference.

```
Sub Test() 

    Dim IE As Object 

    Sheets("Sheet3").Select 
    Range("A1:A1000") = "" ' erase previous data
    Range("A1").Select 

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
        With IE 
            .Visible = True 
            .Navigate "http://www.aarp.org/" ' should work for any URL
            Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop 
        End With 

        IE.ExecWB 17, 0 '// SelectAll
        IE.ExecWB 12, 2 '// Copy selection
        ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False 
        Range("A1").Select 
        IE.Quit 

End Sub
```