# Excel VBA: Iterate Through DIV Contents - Paste In Individual Cells

Tags: vba, excel

I found some code on Stack Exchange, of all places, and was able to modify it 95% of the way for my needs but one last issue keeps cropping up, all the DIVs in the parent DIV paste into one cell, I want them to post to individual cells in my worksheet. The code came from Stack Overflow user "Portland Runner" and the original post can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561527/vba-to-copy-website-data). The HTML I'm up against looks something like this:

```
<div class="right-header">
 <div>Entry 1</div>
 <div>Entry 2</div>
 <div>Entry 3</div>
 <div>Entry 4</div>
 <div>Entry 5</div>
 <div>Entry 6</div>
</div>
```

The child DIVs have no IDs, Classes, or Styles, just information surrounded by a lonesome DIV tag. This all gets dumped into a single cell where I'd like instead for it to be dumped into Al (Entry 1), B1 (Entry 2), C1 (Entry 3), etc. The original code is as follows:

```
Sub extract()
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument

Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
IE.Visible = False
IE.Navigate2 "C:\Users\john\Documents\Test.html"

' Wait while IE loading
Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Set html = IE.document
Set holdingsClass = html.getElementsByClassName("right-header")
Dim results As Variant
   results = Split(holdingsClass(0).textContent, vbLf)

   cntr = 1
   For i = LBound(results) To UBound(results)
       If Trim(results(i)) <> "" Then
           Select Case Right(Trim(results(i)), 1)
               Case "<div>"
                   Range("B" & cntr) = CStr(Trim(results(i)))
               Case "%"
                   Range("C" & cntr).Value = Trim(results(i))
                   cntr = cntr + 1
               Case 0
                   Range("C" & cntr).Value = Trim(results(i))
               Case Else
                   Range("A" & cntr).Value = Trim(results(i))
           End Select
       End If
   Next i
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Value = holdingsClass(0).textContent

'Cleanup
IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thank you any and all for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiled but not tested:

```
Sub extract()
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim topDiv, div, childDivs, tc As String, cntr

    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    IE.Visible = False
    IE.Navigate2 "C:\Users\john\Documents\Test.html"

    ' Wait while IE loading
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Set topDiv = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("right-header")(0)

    Set childDivs = topDiv.getElementsByTagName("div")

    cntr = 2

    For Each div In childDivs
        tc = Trim(div.textContent)
        If tc <> "" Then
            Select Case Right(tc, 1)
                Case "<div>"
                    'not sure whether you should be seeing HTML in textcontent...?
                    Range("B" & cntr) = CStr(tc)
                Case "%"
                    Range("C" & cntr).Value = tc
                    cntr = cntr + 1
                Case 0
                    Range("C" & cntr).Value = tc
                Case Else
                    Range("A" & cntr).Value = tc
            End Select
        End If
    Next div

    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Value = topDiv.textContent

    'Cleanup
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks to be real close, it did pretty much what was expected but it appears as if the code kept populating A2 over and over leaving "Entry 6" in the original example as the last and remaining entry in A2. So close! I appreciate the help and response.

Comment: Figured it out myself, I put cntr = cntr + 1 after the End If and it works! Thank you so much again!